# Is it possible to use for loop inside a switch?

Tags: php, for-loop, switch-statement

I'm attempting something like the following:

```
 switch ($p) {
    foreach ($modules as $m) {
    case '"'.$mod.'"':
    include 'modules/'.$m.'/cases.php';
    break;
    }
 }
```

but can't get it to work. Is it possible to use a for loop in this manner, inside a switch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it is...

Basic and shorter solution:

```
foreach($modules AS $m) {
    if($p == $m) {
        include 'modules/'.$m.'/cases.php';
        break;
    }
}
```

but the best would be:

```
if(in_array($p, $modules))
    include 'modules/'.$p.'/cases.php';
```

Comment: if (in_array($p, $modules)) include "modules/$p/cases.php";

is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes and No

You need to move the foreach outside the `switch` or inside the `case` selector. I'm not sure why the switch() is even necessary. Why not just do whatever to each module without running it through a switch?

And most languages don't let you jump into inner blocks. Even when they do, it's not a good practice.

Comment: I'm actually trying to dynamically include a set of cases based on the section (module) being viewed, hence the switch. I need to include the cases for only one module at a time, where $p is the module.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some form of [Duff's device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) - but I don't think that's legal anywhere outside of C.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to do something like determine if $p is in $modules, and if so, include it, there's probably a better way to do that than a switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can use a loop inside a switch. You can't, however, do what you're trying to do there; it just doesn't work. And I don't see any point to it either. Why not just have an array with the module names as keys, and then do

```
if ($modules[$p]) {
  include $modules[$p];
} else {
  // not found...
}
```

or something to that effect?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do such a thing : immediatly a switch statement, the only thing you can use is a `case` or a `default` statement.

That is what the error you are getting is telling you, btw :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH, expecting T_CASE or T_DEFAULT or '}'
```

If you want a loop and a swith, you'll have to either put the loop "arround" the whole switch statement, or "inside" a case statement.