# Find correct value between different pairs of options

Tags: php

I need to display an icon depending on different time of the day.

- Icon 1 – 1am to 7am
- Icon 2 – 7am to 8am
- Icon 3 – 8am to 12pm
- Icon 4 – 12pm to 1pm
- Icon 5 – 1pm to 6pm
- Icon 6 – 6 to 8pm
- Icon 7 – 8pm to 12am.

These icons and time pairs will come dynamically from database.

How can i create a loop to find the correct icon for any time of the day?

Comment: your question is not clear.first you mentioned above the icon and the corresponding time frames and than you are saying these will come dynamically from database.

Comment: Icons and corresponding time frames are sample data, that will be stored in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$current_time = date('G');

while($resultset=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result))
{
    if($current_time >= $resultset["time_range1"] && $current_time <= $resultset["time_range2"])
    {
        //set right icon

     }
    //another options condition is as..put here
}
```

// i just suggest as per my logic

Answer (score 2):

It could be a simple switch that returns correct value.
Something like:

```
$current_time = date('G');

switch(TRUE) {
    case($current_time >= 1 && $current_time <= 7):
        //set right icon
        //another options...
}
```

Another option is to do it directly from SQL query, but I'm not sure how good this solution is. Like `SELECT icon FROM table WHERE start_time => CURTIME() AND end_time <= CURTIME()` - but in that case you should store **hours** in proper date format.

Comment: i will do +1 if you resolve this point of OP 'These icons and time pairs will come dynamically from database.
'

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, i need to store time ranges in database, so that admin can change them. But i guess i can create cases in switch statement dynamically with a loop.

Comment: Unfortunately loop is not supported inside switch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391211/is-it-possible-to-use-for-loop-inside-a-switch

Comment: Ok, than the answer depends on this: will you always have **7 icons** or less? In that case you can output those values from database like `$start_time[n]` and `$end_time[n]` and set them accordingly for each `case`. You can't create php operators dynamically, unless you making code generator.

Comment: Number of icons can change, as admin have ability to add them, i don't want to make them fixed in any way.

Comment: Than read edit on my answer. You can do it with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
// Prints the day

$d= mysql_query("SELECT  * from result ");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($d);
$now = date("gA");
echo $now;
if($now=='1AM' or $now=='2AM' or $now=='3AM'or $now=='4AM' or $now=='5AM' or $now=='6AM')
{
echo $row['Icon 1'];
}
elseif($now=='7AM')
{
echo $row['Icon 2'];
}
elseif(  $now=='8AM' or $now=='9AM' or $now=='10AM' or $now=='11AM')
{

echo $row['Icon 3'];
}
elseif($now=='12PM' or $now=='1PM' or $now=='2PM' or $now=='3PM' or $now=='4PM' or $now=='5PM' )
{

echo $row['Icon 4'];
}
elseif( $now=='6PM' or  $now=='7PM'  )
{

echo $row['Icon 5'];
}
elseif( $now=='8PM' or  $now=='9PM' or $now=='10PM' or $now=='11PM' or $now=='12AM'  )
{

echo $row['Icon 6'];
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, don't code like this.